# Does taking the limit in one argument preserve regularity in another argument?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, uniform-convergence, measurable-functions, pointwise-convergence

**Preliminaries**

Let $T>0$ be a positive constant, $d,n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ be natural numbers and $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space.

For $m \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$, we define a sequence of functions

$$X_m : \Omega \times [0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d $$

such that, for all $m \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$,

$$ \omega \mapsto X_m(\omega, t, \theta) $$
is $\mathcal{G}/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ measurable, 
$$ t \mapsto X_m(\omega, t, \theta)  $$
is continuous, and 
$$ \theta \mapsto X_m(\omega, t, \theta)  $$
is continuous as well.

Now assume, that there is an $A \subseteq \Omega$ with $\mathbb{P}(A) =  1$, such that for all $\tilde{\omega} \in A$, it holds that, for all $t \in [0,T]$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$ \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} X_m(\tilde{\omega}, t, \theta) $$
exists and is finite.

Now define a new function

$$ X : \Omega \times [0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d $$
via

$$ X(\omega, t, \theta) := \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{1}_{A}(\omega) X_m(\omega, t, \theta). $$

Moreover, we assume, that, for all $\tilde{\omega} \in A$ the sequence of functions
$$ t \mapsto X_m(\tilde{\omega}, t, \theta)  $$
converges uniformly on $[0,T]$ towards 
$$t \mapsto X(\tilde{\omega}, t, \theta).$$

**Question**

Can we conclude from all of this, that 
$$ \theta \mapsto X_m(\omega, t, \theta)  $$
is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) / \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d) $ -measurable? And can we even conclude from this, that 
$$ \theta \mapsto X_m(\omega, t, \theta)  $$
is continuous?

Which conditions would be sufficient to guarantee either measurability or even continuity for
$$ \theta \mapsto X_m(\omega, t, \theta)  ?$$